# Dynamically changing rectangles colors

Tags: python, kivy

In example below, there are two rectangles drawn in canvas of FloatLayout.

The goal is to create something like a simple pixel art drawing app where the user can draw rectangles and change their color (for example color of rectangle under mouse), so I can’t create these rectangles in kv file.

So in this demo example I just want to change the color of rectangle under the mouse.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

KV = """
FloatLayout
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 512, 512
    on_touch_down: app.test(*args[1].pos)
"""


class MyApp(App):

    color = ListProperty((1,1,1,1))

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

        self.init_rects()

    def init_rects(self):
        with self.root.canvas:
            x,y = self.root.pos
            w,h = self.root.size

            Color(rgba=(1,1,1,1))
            self.r1 = Rectangle(pos = (x,y), size= (w/2,h))
            Color(rgba=(1,0,0,1))
            self.r2 = Rectangle(pos = (w/2,y), size= (w/2,h))

    def test(self, x,y):
        if x< self.root.center_x:
            print ('I need to color this rectangle (self.r1) to red')
        else:
            print ('I need to color this rectangle (self.r2) to white')

MyApp().run()
```

In this example I store rectangles as self.r1 and self.r2 (because I think further I will need to change them pos or size)

The problem is I didn't find an example of how to change only one rectangle color, and not to change other colors.

I have a stupid solution (below) - every time to create a new rectangle. But I am sure that this is a bad solution when there will be a lot of rectangles

```
    def test(self, touch_x, touch_y):
        with self.root.canvas:

            x,y = self.root.pos
            w,h = self.root.size

            if touch_x< self.root.center_x:
                Color(rgba=(1,0,0,1))
                self.r1 = Rectangle(pos = (x,y), size= (w/2,h))
            else:
                Color(rgba=(1,1,1,1))
                self.r2 = Rectangle(pos = (w/2,y), size= (w/2,h))
```

Roughly speaking I miss something like `Rectangle(rgba=...)`

What could be the solution in this case?

Comment: Fun project, coincidentally this is almost identical to the first project I made in Kivy when I was learning :) The way I did it was to create a gridlayout, fill it with a ton of `Button`s that had no background (`your_button.background_normal=""`), and set the `on_release` method of the `Button`s to set the button's color (`your_button.background_color=(1,0,0,1)`). Let me know if that helps or if you need a more concrete example.

Comment: @Erik I have doubts about performance in this case, if you have a lot of widgets (cells), for example, several thousand widgets )

Comment: The slow part was loading all the widgets, but they were all quite responsive to mouse events. I think I went up to a 128x128 grid (~16000 widgets) and it took maybe 10 seconds to load. It was quite decent, but I can't remember the numbers exactly. You are correct though, there are certainly better ways to do it if you want to have other people using it. The `.export_to_png` function came in handy as well to save the drawing in case you haven't come across that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Color` instead of trying to change the `Rectangle`. Here is a modification of your code that demonstrates this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

KV = """
FloatLayout
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 512, 512
    on_touch_down: app.test(*args[1].pos)
"""


class MyApp(App):

    color = ListProperty((1,1,1,1))

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

        self.init_rects()

    def init_rects(self):
        with self.root.canvas:
            x,y = self.root.pos
            w,h = self.root.size

            self.c1 = Color(rgba=(1,1,1,1))
            Rectangle(pos = (x,y), size= (w/2,h))
            self.c2 = Color(rgba=(1,0,0,1))
            Rectangle(pos = (w/2,y), size= (w/2,h))

    def test(self, x,y):
        if x< self.root.center_x:
            print ('I need to color this rectangle (self.r1) to red')
            self.c1.rgba = (1,0,0,1)
        else:
            print ('I need to color this rectangle (self.r2) to white')
            self.c2.rgba = (1,1,1,1)

MyApp().run()
```